# Como contar caracteres de uma String ignorando os espaços em brancos?

Tags: java

Estou tentando fazer um `return` na variável para contar quantas letras existem na palavra digitada e ignorar os espaços digitados, mas não sei como juntar o `length` com o `trim`, diz a seguinte mensagem:

> Cannot invoke trim() on the primitive type int.

```
    public Integer contaCarateresSemEspaços(String texto) {
    return texto.length().trim();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`length` é um método da classe `String`, este método retorna um inteiro.

`trim` também é um método da classe `String`, porém você está invocando `trim` no retorno de `length`, que é um inteiro. Inteiros não possuem o método `trim`, por isso o erro.

Se por outro lado você estivesse invocando os métodos na seguinte ordem:

```
texto.trim().length()
```

Primeiro `trim` seria executado, retornando uma `String`, e então `length` seria executado sobre essa `String` retornada, o que é um código válido.

Porém `trim` só irá remover os espaços no começo e no final da sua `String`, se você quiser remover todos os espaços em branco, você terá que substitui-los com o método `replaceAll`:

```
texto.replaceAll("\\s","").length()
```

Comment: Só lembrando que `\s` também vai remover outros caracteres, como o TAB e quebras de linha (dependendo da string e do que vc precisa, pode fazer diferença ou não). Se quer remover **somente** os espaços, use `replaceAll(" ", "")`

Answer (score 3):

Boa noite, se você quiser contar somente os caracteres a função `Trim()` não é indicada, ela remove somente os espaços do inicio e fim da `string`. Ao invés disso usse a função `Replace()`.

Exemplo:

```
        string var = "meu valor estatico";
        Console.WriteLine(var.Replace(" ", "").Length);
```

Comment: ahh perfeito, eu esqueci de dizer que também preciso remover os espaços do inicio e do fim da string, como fazer ?

Comment: Se quiser remover somente do inicio e fim use a função Trim(), rimou kkkk.

Answer (score 2):

Se você mudar a ordem do retorno do seu método, o erro deixará de acontecer, no entanto não fará o que você deseja.

O sensato seria você retornar o valor `length` após remover todos os espaços em branco:

```
return texto.replace(" ", "").length();
```

Dessa forma você retornará a quantidade de caracteres sem os espaços em branco.